# Convergence of series $a^x$ where $a < 1$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> I'm checking for convergence of the series 
>   $$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}a^{x}$$
>    when $a<1$ and $a>0$.

My analysis,

$a_0 = 1, a_1 = a<1, a_2 = a^2 < 1\dots  a_{\infty} = \frac{1}{(\text{something})^{\infty}} = 0 $.

So, $a_0 > a_1 > a_2 > ... > a_{\infty}$ **converges**.

I substituted $a^{x}=e^{x\ln a}$ in the integral test, but it yields $e^{\infty}$,

$$\int_{x=0}^{\infty}a^x = \int_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{x\ln a} = \left.\frac{e^{x\ln a}}{\ln a}\right|_{x=0}^\infty = e^\infty - e^0$$

By the above analysis the sequence does not converge. What am I doing wrong?.

Comment: $\log(a)<0$ for $a<1$ and $\lim_{x\to infty}e^{-x}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<a<1$ then $\ln(a) < 0$.

Comment: Thanks. after integration i would get 0 - 1/ln(a) am I correct?.

Comment: It would actually be $\frac{1}{\ln a}$ because of the negative in the log.